# validar inputs y habilitar botón

Tags: javascript

Lo que necesito es validar el formulario de la segunda sección de la pestaña.

Si hay algún campo vacío de los 4 que aparecen no ocultos o transparentes el botón debería estar deshabilitado.

Si ya tienen los 4 datos, pues que se habilite el botón.

El problema es que yo agrego los dos elementos y por una razón se habilita el botón siendo que el ultimo input no tiene datos. y si yo agrego un 3er elemento serian 6 campos a llenar o modificar, porque el digitador puede pasar a borrar una cantidad e igual debiese estar deshabilitado el botón a pesar que los otros 5 estén llenos con datos
los inputs son `shoppingCartItemQuantity_` y `precio_`.

Resumen:

1. Dejar botón visible cuando todos los input estén llenos con datos
2. Colocar foco al inputs a llenar al primero que encuentre vacío

```js
const id_prod = document.querySelector('#first-tab >#articulos>#productos_content>.tr >.id_n').textContent;
console.log(id_prod)

const tbody = document.querySelector('#second-tab >.shoppingCartItemsContainer > #form2 >#tabla >.tbody')
function updateCantidadNuevo(input) {
  if(input.checkValidity()){
   input.setAttribute("data-oldvalue", input.value);
  }
  else{
    input.value = input.getAttribute("data-oldvalue") || input.min;
  }
}
function add(id, cantidad=1){
  let input = document.querySelector('#shoppingCartItemQuantity_'+id);
  input.value= input.valueAsNumber + cantidad;
  updateCantidadNuevo(input);
  
console.log(id,input);
}



const addToShoppingCartButtons = document.querySelectorAll('#first-tab > #articulos > tbody > tr > .td > .button')
console.log(addToShoppingCartButtons)
addToShoppingCartButtons.forEach((addToCartButton) => {
  addToCartButton.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked);
  
  
  
  
  
  function addToCartClicked(event) {
  const button = event.target;
  
  const item = button.closest('.tr');

  const id_prod = item.querySelector('.id_n').textContent
  const cantidad_disponible = item.querySelector('.cantidad_disponible').textContent;
  const talla = item.querySelector('.talla').textContent;

  
  addItemToShoppingCart(id_prod,  cantidad_disponible, talla);
}
function addItemToShoppingCart(id_prod,cantidad_disponible,talla) {
    

  if(cantidad_disponible!=0){
  const elementsTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('title');

  for (let i = 0; i < elementsTitle.length; i++) {
    if (elementsTitle[i].innerText === id_prod) {
     
      return;
    }
  }

  const tr = document.createElement('tr')
    tr.classList.add('ItemCarrito')
     tr.setAttribute("id", `tr_${id_prod}`);

  Content = `
     <th scope="row">${id_prod}</th>

     <td class="table__productos">
     <input id="id_productos_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${id_prod}" class="id_productos"
    style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">

       <h6 id="title_${id_prod}" class="title" hidden>${id_prod}</h6>
     </td>

    
     <td class="table__cantidad_disponible">
     <input id="cantidad_disponible_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${cantidad_disponible}" class="cantidad_disponible"
     style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
      
    </td>

    <td class="table__talla">
    <input id="talla_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${talla}" class="talla"
   style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
      
     </td>

   



    
    
    <td class="table__cantidad">
                <input id="shoppingCartItemQuantity_${id_prod}" max="${cantidad_disponible}" oninput="updateCantidad(this)" class="shopping-cart-quantity-input shoppingCartItemQuantity_${id_prod}" type="number" onblur="habilitar()"
                    value="1" min="1">
                
                </td>
         <td class="table__precio">
     <input required id="precio_${id_prod}" type="text" class="precio"   onchange="CarritoTotalmio()" min="0"onblur="habilitar()">
      
     </td>

     <td class="table__delete">
     <button class="delete btn btn-danger">x</button>
      
    </td>
     `
   
    
   tr.innerHTML = Content 
     tbody.append(tr)
}else{
  console.log("tiene un 0 imposible agregar");
}
}


});

function habilitar() {
  let nombreApellido = document.getElementById("shoppingCartItemQuantity_"+id_prod);
  let email = document.getElementById("precio_"+id_prod);
 
  let enviarBoton = document.getElementById("guardardatos");

  if (nombreApellido.value === '' || email.value === '') {
    enviarBoton.disabled = true;
  } else {
    enviarBoton.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
input[type=number] { -moz-appearance:textfield; }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled-2</title>
  
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
   
</head>
<body>



  

<section class="section">
      <div class="tabs">
         <ul class="tabs-menu">
          <li class="is-active" data-target="first-tab"><a>Tab one</a></li>
          <li data-target="second-tab"><a>Tab two</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content" id="first-tab">

      <table id="articulos"class="table">
        <thead>
           
            <tr>
            
            <TH>id </TH>
            <TH>id del producto</TH>
            <TH>cantidad_disponible</TH>
            <TH>talla zapatos</TH>
                <TH>Añadir</TH>
              <TH>Añadir</TH>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody  id="productos_content">
             <tr class="tr">
         
            
            <td class="id_n">15<td>
            <td class="cantidad_disponible"> 3</td>
            <td class="talla"> 36</td>
              
<td class="td"><button id="15" onclick="add(15)"   class="button">Añadir</button></td>
  
        </tr> 
       
       <tr class="tr">
         
            
            <td class="id_n">1<td>
            <td class="cantidad_disponible"> 7</td>
            <td class="talla"> 40</td>
          
<td class="td"><button id="15" onclick="add(1)"   class="button">Añadir</button></td>
    
        </tr> 
        </tbody>
        </table>
    
          </div>



      <div class="tab-content" id="second-tab">
      <div class="shopping-cart-items shoppingCartItemsContainer">
      <form id="form2" action="javascript:habilitar()">

<input type="button" id="guardardatos" value="Guardar" onchange="habilitar()" disabled />
   

      <table id="tabla" class="table">
 
            <tr>
            <TH>id</TH>
            <TH>id del producto</TH>   
            <TH>cantidad_disponible</TH>
            <TH>talla zapatos</TH>          
            <TH>Añadir </TH>    
            </tr>
               <tbody id="carrito_content" class="tbody">
               
        </tbody>
    </table>

      <div class="float-right">
      Total:<input type="text" id="resultado_total" value="0" disabled > </input>

        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>

<script>
    const tabSystem = {
    init(){
        document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-menu').forEach(tabMenu => {
            Array.from(tabMenu.children).forEach((child, ind) => {
                child.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    tabSystem.toggle(child.dataset.target);
                });
                if(child.className.includes('is-active')){
                    tabSystem.toggle(child.dataset.target);
                }
            });
        });
    },
    toggle(targetId){
        document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content').forEach(contentElement=>{
            contentElement.style.display = contentElement.id === targetId ? 'block' : 'none';
            document.querySelector(`[data-target="${contentElement.id}"]`).classList[contentElement.id === targetId ? 'add' : 'remove']('is-active');
        })
    },
};
// use it
tabSystem.init()
</script>


</html>
```

Este es un ejemplo de como debería de funcionar.

Mi código a modificar es el de arriba, ese es el que no funciona

```js
const form = [...document.querySelectorAll('.form__element-input')];
const boton = document.querySelector('#enviar');

form.forEach((input, index) => {
    boton.classList.add('none__send');
    input.addEventListener('input', () => {
        if (form.some(el => el.value.trim() === "")) {
            boton.classList.add('none__send');
        } else {
            boton.classList.remove('none__send');
        }
    })
});
```

```css
.none__send {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" class="form">
    <div class="form__title">
    </div>
    <div class="form__element">
        <input type="number" name="cedula" class="form__element-input"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form__element">
        <input type="number" name="telefono" class="form__element-input"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form__element">
        <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form__element-input"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form__button">
        <button type="submit" id="enviar">enviar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: no hay alguna manera de que puedas formatear tu código mejor? es un spaghetti, esta lleno de saltos de línea y tabulaciones.

Comment: el código ya esta formateado

Answer (score 0):

cambia la funcion *habilitar()* tal que asi:

```
function habilitar() {
  const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.table__cantidad, .table__precio')
  let enviarBoton = document.getElementById("guardardatos");

  [...inputs].every(elem => elem.firstElementChild.value.trim() !== '') 
    ? enviarBoton.disabled = false 
    : enviarBoton.disabled = true
}
```

Se seleccionan los contenedores que contienen los inputs que quieres validar, conviertes esa HTMLCollection a un array para poder usar el método [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) que devuelve verdadero si todos los elementos del arreglo cumple con un predicado, el cual sera que el input dentro del contenedor evaluado no se encuentre vacio. Si el método every devuelve true entonces se habilita el boton, caso contrario se deshabilita.

***nota**: tienes esta función asociada al evento blur, por lo que se ejecutara al perder el foco en cualquiera de los inputs que la llamen y no al cambiar los valores. Si quieres que se habilite o deshabilite el boton 'en tiempo real' debes usar el evento onChange sobre los inputs.*

Comment: me explicas un poco tu cosdigo,? el containers

Comment: function habilitar() {
  const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.table__cantidad, .table__precio')
  let enviarBoton = document.getElementById("guardardatos");

  [...inputs].every(elem => elem.firstElementChild.value.trim() !== '') 
    ? enviarBoton.disabled = false 
    : enviarBoton.disabled = true
}

Comment: @FelipeDeveloper no selecciono directamente los inputs sino sus contenedores es decir, los elementos que los envuelven (clases table__cantidad y table_precios), y después selecciono los inputs a partir de los contenedores con firstElementChild y hago la validacion

Comment: pero ahora que veo podria seleccionar los inputs directamente con las clases 'shopping-cart-quantity-input' y 'precio'

Comment: como seria, si es posible podria colocar codigo ejecutable

Comment: no me funciona, da error en inputs